# Count how many ID's have more than one value in columns -R

Tags: r, count, data.table

Hi i have this dataset:

```
>   id  s1 s2 s3 s4 
    1   "A"  "A"  "NA" "A"
    2   "NA"  "A"  "NA" "A"
    3   "Na"  "NA"  "NA" "A"
    4   "A"  "NA"  "NA" "Na"
    5   "A"  "A"  "NA" "A"
```

I want to count how many ID's have only one value of "A" in either s1, s2, s3, s4. In this case it is only 2 persons (ID 3 and 4). But if i have a large dataset how can I count this ?

Comment: If all the values are 1 or NA then `sum(na.rm=TRUE)` on a row will tell you how many columns are filled.  You can then count how many of those are `==1`.

Comment: What if in my dataset the 1's are a text string fx "groupA"

Comment: you can try `sum(!is.na())` - `is.na()` generates "TRUE" or "FALSE" for each entry as to whether or not it's an NA.  `!` negates this, and `sum()` adds them up (TRUE counts as 1 and FALSE as 0).

Comment: I have updated the questions if it makes better sense now

Comment: No, it's still in a terrible sense because you quote `NA` as `"NA"`. In R, `NA` and `"NA"` have different meanings. The former indicates the missing value and the latter is just a text string and loses all features a missing value owns.

Comment: In addition, you should not share your data like that. You should make your data reproducible, i.e. create a code that is able to produce your data in any computers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```r
which(rowSums(!is.na(df[-1])) == 1)

# [1] 3 4
```

Replace `which()` with `sum()` to get the number of ID that have only 1 non-missing value.

---

###### Update

If unfortunately, you store all `NA` as `"NA"`, `"Na"`, or `"na"`, then use the following code to convert them back to regular `NA` in advance.

```r
df[] <- lapply(df, \(x) { x[x %in% c('NA', 'Na', 'na')] <- NA; x })
```

Comment: I have updated the questions - i forgot that my values are only text strings

Comment: My answer works for any data types, on the premise that those `NA`s are genuine `NA`s, instead of `"NA"` or `"Na"` or `"na"`.

Answer (score 0):

Checks for "A" in the string

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  filter(rowSums(across(s1:s4, ~ str_detect(.x, "A")), na.rm = TRUE) == 1)

# A tibble: 2 × 5
     id s1    s2    s3    s4   
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <lgl> <chr>
1     3 Na    NA    NA    A    
2     4 A     NA    NA    Na
```